# how to read .pdf and .Docfile using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

How can I View Pdf and Document files using  html,For example company details may be in Document file or pdf file. When i click that company's link, means what ever it is pdf or doc i need to view it in html(jsp) page browser it self ..please help me..

Comment: Do you need to read the documents, or just display them? If you pose your question more precisely and carefully, you're more likely to get a useful response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view it in HTML, then you need to convert it to HTML. Find a library for the file format that can do that for you.

If you just want to view in in the browser, then install a plug in that supports the format (distributed with Adobe Reader and Microsoft Office respectively for IE at least) or use a browser with native support (Chrome has native PDF support for instance) then just link to the files.